# Phonegap - navigator.app.backHistory() not working on HTML back button

Tags: android, ios, cordova, back-button, back-button-control

In my app i am using phonegap 2.6.For back button, I am using the following function

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    alert("hello");
    navigator.app.backHistory();
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
```

The above function **works fine when I click on the device's hardware back button**. But when I click on the back button it is not working.

I have designed my back button as below:

```
<a class="ui-link" href="#" rel="external" onclick="onBackKeyDown()">
        <img src="images/icon-back.png" alt="Phone" border="0">
</a>
```

But this button is working fine for this `navigator.app.exitApp();` (application exit).

```
//Working Fine
function onBackKeyDown() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}

//Not Working
function onBackKeyDown() {
    navigator.app.backHistory();
}
```

but not working for `navigator.app.backHistory();`.

Comment: For someone who came here looking for the same problem with cordova 3.8 and ios 9.0 check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761206/cordova-window-history-back-not-working-on-html-back-button-in-ios-9/32777611#32777611

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have tried 3 separate things when I faced the same situation:

- `window.history.back()`
- `navigator.app.backHistory();`
- `History.go(-1);`

Individually, none of these solve the problem. I put all 3 things together and much to my surprise it worked. I really don't know what is behind it.

Then I decreased to two functions and removed:

- `window.history.back()`

Now I am using this function and it is working fine.

```
//Works Fine
function onBackKeyDown() {
    history.go(-1);
    navigator.app.backHistory();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the attribute data-rel="back" on an anchor, any clicks on that anchor will mimic the back button, going back one history entry and ignoring the anchor's default href.

Comment: Pretty sure data-rel="back" is only being used in jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

it depends where you are: 
on my windowsphone 8.1 lumia 925, it works     **history.go(-1);**, 
while **navigator.app.backHistory();** causes an exception before crashing.

On my Android (I believe the majority), **navigator.app.backHistory();** works properly.

Answer (score 1):

This might help some people, as it helped me fix the history.go(-1) not working in google chrome browser.

```js
// Doesn't work in Chrome browser
function onBackKeyDown() {
    history.go(-1);
    navigator.app.backHistory();
}
```

```js
// Does work in Chrome browser
function onBackKeyDown() {
    history.go(-1);
    return false; //needed in chrome to prevent about:blank page.
    navigator.app.backHistory();
    return false; //needed in chrome to prevent about:blank page.
}
```

Im no expert at all in jQuery, but thought it might help someone, as I was looking for this answer but couldn't find it at first.

Answer (score -2):

### Solved! Stop getting "TypeError: navigator.app is undefined"

A function I created that will first check what device you're on and then apply the relevant script:

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
        // IOS DEVICE
        history.go(-1);
    } else if (userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
        // ANDROID DEVICE
        navigator.app.backHistory();
    } else {
        // EVERY OTHER DEVICE
        history.go(-1);
    }
}
```

Call function by adding this to your back link/button:

```
onclick="onBackKeyDown()"
```