# Android: "onBackPressed" is only called from the first page of Cordova 3 webview, can't be overridden from inner pages

Tags: android, cordova, webview, back

I am building a Cordova 3 app.
I'm loading a url to my appview and on certain cases i'm opening a fullscreen view on top of the appview. In these cases I would like the back button to only remove my top view, and not perform the built in "goBack" method. 
I didn't manage to override the back click behaviour in inner pages. I noticed I'm getting to my "onBackPressed" listener function only when I click "back" from my initial URL page, inner pages seem to disable the "back" event propagation and always perform browser back navigation.

I found this post: [Override Android Backbutton behavior only works on the first page with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631933/override-android-backbutton-behavior-only-works-on-the-first-page-with-phonegap) but it seemed only relevant to older cordova versions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem i faced, I simply fix this by adding the following code in my each HTML page

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad()
    {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    }
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton",noth,false);
    }
    function noth()
    {
        //code for what happends if back button is pressed
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
```

Using this code i created a phonegap app it shows a confirm message like 'exit app ?' if you pressed back button in main html file while in other cases 
it shows previous html page
For reference:
[Phonegap - navigator.app.backHistory() not working on HTML back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542118/phonegap-navigator-app-backhistory-not-working-on-html-back-button)