# Implementing Back Button functionality for wp8 cordova application

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, browser-history

I tried to implement the back button functionality in my wp8 cordova application , which on pressing the hardware back button on device should navigate to the previous page of the app .

What i have done

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function init() {
  //some code
}

function onResume() {
  //some code   
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
   window.history.back();
   return false; 
}
```

I also tried replacing the "window.history.back();" with "navigator.app.backHistory();" which also doesnot seems to work

Then i tried putting the code in try catch block

```
try
{
navigator.app.backHistory();
//window.history.back(); 
}
catch (e)
{
console.log("exception: " + e.message); 
}
```

which also seems to fail .Whatever I do the app seems to exit out of the app rather than moving backward and the funny thing is when i try this in the IE console it seems to work perfectly

Please help with this guys

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the 10 Lines of code before and after your "addEventListener("backbutton...".

Comment: @Sithys hi ,can you explain for what you need that..?

Comment: The EventListener for the Backbutton will only work if you have a deviceready eventlistener which calls the backbutton eventlistener if the deviceready is successfully fired.

Comment: hi @Sithys my code will look like this

function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
        document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
       document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
function onBackKeyDown() {
   window.history.back();
   return false; 
}

something like that

Comment: Could you please edit that inside your first post and into a code tag?

Comment: @Sithys can take a look now , have edited the snippet

Answer (score 6):

So lets try another way which should work for wp8. This Method requires the WinJS Framework and will work like this:

In the onDeviceReady function you're going to use this code:

```
if (device.platform == "windows") {
    // Get the back button working in WP8.1
    WinJS.Application.onbackclick = function () {
        onBackKeyDown();
        return true; // This line is important, without it the app closes.
    }
}
else {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
```

Now just add a function to handle the onBackKeyDown event and that's it:

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Back key pressed, do something here
}
```

The standard method of Cordova to hook into the BackButton-Event would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Back Button Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the back button
    //
    function onBackKeyDown() {
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Important here is **to call the BackButton-Event inside the DeviceReady function**!

Comment: Hi, doesnot seems to work in the way i wanted  the app is navigating back but to the first page skips every intermediate pages 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did i understand you correct, the function i posted navigates you to the first page every time you click it independent of the page you actually are? Please provide the code you bound to the onBackKeyDown function

Comment: Try this for the onBackKeyDown function: history.go(-1);

Comment: Hi already tried can u give the email so that i can send you a sample code so that you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would like to help you, but i don't have a WP8 mobile Phone. Look into this question and try the solutions given there. Let me know if that doesn't help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542118/phonegap-navigator-app-backhistory-not-working-on-html-back-button