# $.mobile.changePage('#id') not working after ajax call in IOS 9

Tags: ios, cordova, navigation

$.mobile.changePage('#id') is not working after calling web service using AJAX, we received response but screen can't navigate to other screen using Cordova 5.1.1.

Comment: Setting of `window.location.hash` is asynchronous in the iOS 9.0 UIWebview (used by Cordova/Phonegap) - see [this bug report](https://openradar.appspot.com/22186109) for details. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761206/cordova-window-history-back-not-working-on-html-back-button-in-ios-9) for potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library. Worked for me on the digest issues.

https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the App Transport Security (ATS) and change the setting if you're compiling your code in xcode. This issue is as a result of the update on iOS9.
You then need to edit your info.plist file and add the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
<dict> 
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

I hope this helps!