# How to go back to previous page using javascript in phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Quiz Application</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      function ready() {
        if (document.getElementById("rb1").checked) {
          alert("correct");
        } else if (document.getElementById("rb2").checked) {
          alert("incorrect");
        } else {
          alert("incorrect");
        }

        function prevpage() {
          document.location=document.history.back();
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="body2">
  <form method="post">
    <center><h1>Quiz Application</h1></center><br><br>
    <center>Is JAVA Object Oriented Language ?<br><br>
    <radiogroup>
      <input type="radio"  id="rb1"/>Yes<br>
      <input type="radio"  id="rb2"/>No<br>
      <input type="radio"  id="rb3"/>May Be<br>
      <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Freeze" onclick="ready();"/><br>
      <input type="submit" id="next" value="Previous Question" onclick="prevpage();"/></center>
    </radiogroup>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above is my code for redirecting to first page which is not working .
Please help me for redirecting on first page.
I went through many options like window.location=-window.history.back(); ,window.history.back(1/-1) but none of them working.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How are they not working? What happends? Any error messages in the console? Also, could you please remove all code not directly related to your question. Please read [MCVE].

Comment: it gives error file cannot be opened sir

Comment: Please add that information, with the exact wording of the error message, to you question. Also you might want to include some information on what kind of file the previous page is, since it seems to be the source of the problem. And you should check if it works when the previos page is an ordinary one.

Comment: i have wrote below sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it should work

```
function prevPage() {
history.go(-1);
navigator.app.backHistory();
```

}

Comment: not working @Soorapadman sir. its document not a web page sir

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: i am checking on emulator .its using android phonegap

Comment: can you change  type submit to button and check ?

Comment: my guess you should see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542118/phonegap-navigator-app-backhistory-not-working-on-html-back-button

Comment: 10-27 19:10:45.777: E/Web Console(778): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: prevpage at file:///android_asset/www/next.html:38
its giving this error after writing your code

Comment: it is look like you jquery plugin have some issue please check