# How to close html file javascript

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap

I'm opening a new html file on button press using this:

```
window.location = "menu.html";
```

I want to go back to the index.html file in my "menu" activity after a button press.
I tried using

```
window.location = "index.html";
```

But it creates a new screen and if I click the return buton to go to my homepage it returns to the previous activities. Also

```
    window.opener.location = '/redirect.html';
    window.close();
```

Doesn't work. So how do I close the menu activity to go back to my main activity.

PS: should I use window.location or window.location.href to open new html file

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using

```
    history.go(-1);
    navigator.app.backHistory();
```

sugested in this answer:
[Phonegap - navigator.app.backHistory() not working on HTML back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542118/phonegap-navigator-app-backhistory-not-working-on-html-back-button)

Also the href on the end of window.location.href is used for links so you should use just window.location

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.open("menu.html", "menu")`. In addition to opening the file you can pass in a second parameter to the `.open` method and the next time you want to open the menu.html file you can using `window.open("menu.html", "menu")` it will open the already opened file in the browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: This is opening a screen but its stretched out and on the top its showing my path to the file. Could work with some tweaking and changing the dimentions of my images but I found a simpeler solution.